# With the Openshift Bronze plan, do I still get 3 free small gears but no idling?

Tags: openshift

I'm now running a small plugin backend on the free plan, but sometimes it idles and takes 20+ sec to start. If I upgrade to the bronze plan, will it never idle then? And do I get to keep the 3 free gears?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've upgraded to the bronze plan over 1.5 years ago to overcome the free plan restrictions. It is really an upgrade without disadvantages. You still get 3 free gears, and the applications never idle due to inactivity.

Additionally you may benefit from

- custom SSL certificates for own domains
- up to 16 gears (e.g. useful when you have 2 apps and 1 jenkins server, you need temporary jenkins slaves for builds)
- different gear sizes
- additional storage options
- manage teams

Please see https://www.openshift.com/pricing/plan-comparison.html for all details.

Comment: OpenShift appear to have updated their policy and now idle gears on both the Bronze and Silver plans after [7 days without external requests](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/plan-comparison.html).

Comment: Redhat appears to have updated their policy again, and now the Bronze plan never idles, but the Free plan idles after 1 day.